# How to append an Image on two or more dom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm finishing up my battleship project and want to add ship images. Before if a player places a ship at a certain coordinate, I just change the color of the divs as an indication of ship being placed. Now I want to place ( append ) images dynamically.

```
            <div class="gameBoard">
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
            </div>
```

The div gameboard above represents my board in the dom. And each divs represent each individual boxs where the players will attack each other. So how can I add one images on lets say to or more divs, so that the image span across those divs.

Comment: While you can use CSS to resize an image to fit a DIV, i don't think it's possible to stretch it to encompass multiple divs. My first thought was you could cut an image into multiple pieces and put each piece on a div.

Comment: Ya, I think its more a css problem then a js one. Anyways im trying to use overflow: visible to place ship at the first div and let to overflow into the second div.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function addImage(a,b){
   document.querySelectorAll(".grid")[a].style.background = "url(ship.jpg)"; 
   document.querySelectorAll(".grid")[b].style.background = "url(ship.jpg)";
}
<div class="grid" onclick='addImage(3,4)'></div>
```

Comment: will it not append the two images on two different divs ?